# Abort: cannot apply a patch over an already active patch

Tags: merge, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree, shelve

I am using [`Source Tree`](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) as a Mercurial client.

I made changes and save them in `Shelve`. Now, I am unanble to `unshelve` them, get error:

> abort: cannot apply a patch over an already active patch

What can I do now? How can I get my changes from shelve?

---

Command to unshelve: `hg unshelve -y ui.merge=internal:merge edit-request-20160511`

---

I've discard all pending changes, but it doesn't help

Comment: Any chances you have MQ enabled and some MQ-patch applied to repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found possible solution.

As I understand, In shelve I have changed file. After shelving it, I have made to this file another changes which is commited. And because of it, I am unable to unshelve changes now.

But I've tried to update repository to commit from which I've created my shelve. After it I was able to unshelve changes.